# Converting a list of dictionaries to a single dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuple values formatted like such:

```
[{'name': 'name', 'value': 'Zach'}, 
{'name': 'email', 'value': 'zach@gmail.com'}, 
{'name': 'age', 'value': '21'}]
```

I am trying to line up a dictionary object using the right key/values. This is the code I have been able to come up with so far:

```
msg_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in msg_ls)
print(msg_dict)
```

This is printing

```
{'name': 'value'}
{'name': 'value'}
{'name': 'value'}
```

while I need for it to read

```
'name': Zach
'email': zach@gmail.com
'age': 21
```

Comment: Those aren't tuples.

Comment: `{y['name'] : y['value'] for y in x}`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Or the obligatory functional `dict(map(itemgetter('name', 'value'), data))` ;)

Comment: @miradulo I believe the time to post an answer has already passed :-(

Answer (score 5):

Note that this assumes that every element in your list is dictionary with the "name" and "value" keys. Also note that dictionaries are generally unordered (no longer the case in the latest versions of python, but most installed versions are not the latest versions).

```
data = [
    {'name': 'name', 'value': 'Zach'}, 
    {'name': 'email', 'value': 'zach@gmail.com'}, 
    {'name': 'age', 'value': '21'}
]

new_dict = {x['name']: x['value'] for x in data}

new_dict
```

Gives me:

```
{'age': '21', 'email': 'zach@gmail.com', 'name': 'Zach'}
```